# If statement not working C#

Tags: c#

I'm not sure if I'm just really tired and missing something obvious or there is something wrong with my program. Basically my if statement condition is not working.

```
public bool check(string nextvaluebinary)
        {
            bool test = true;

            for (int i = -1; i < 8; ++i)
            {
                i++;
                System.Console.WriteLine(nextvaluebinary[i] + " " + nextvaluebinary[i + 1]);
                if (nextvaluebinary[i] == 1)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Activated");
                    if (nextvaluebinary[i + 1] == 0)
                    {
                        test = false;
                        System.Console.WriteLine("false");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    test = true;
                }

                if (test == false)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return test;
        }
```

I'm passing in the string 0001010110 and im getting an output of:

```
0 0
0 1
0 1
0 1
1 0
```

but no "activated" or "false" even though the last one is "1 0". Again sorry if this is a dumb question and any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, instead of incrementing `i` manually inside the loop, you can use the for loop to do that instead:  `for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i += 2)`.  Not that it makes much difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're comparing a char against an int. The check you're attempting carries a completely different meaning than what you're trying to accomplish. You need to either check if its equal to '1' or cast the char to an int first so you can do a numeric comparison.

```
if (nextvaluebinary[i] == '1')
```

Comment: Well "never be true" is not quite right.  There is an ASCII character with the value of 1.  It's the fact that the char originated as a string character instead of some random 16-bit integer.  As an aside, you _could_ also subtract a magical `0x30` to make the ASCII value for any digit (like '0') into the actual number it represents.

Answer (score 2):

Since `nextvaluebinary` is a `String`, this comparison will succeed only if that string has a null character, i.e. `'\0'`:

```
if (nextvaluebinary[i + 1] == 0)
```

It looks like you are looking for a zero *digit* character, instead, so you should write

```
if (nextvaluebinary[i + 1] == '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Equals is used with char to int. So that will use char code.

Use this

```
    public static bool check(string nextvaluebinary)
    {
        bool test = true;

        for (int i = -1; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            i++;
            System.Console.WriteLine(nextvaluebinary[i] + " " + nextvaluebinary[i + 1]);
            if (nextvaluebinary[i] == '1')
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Activated");
                if (nextvaluebinary[i + 1] == '0')
                {
                    test = false;
                    System.Console.WriteLine("false");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                test = true;
            }

            if (test == false)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return test;
    }
```